# Find a group of order $60$ with subgroup of all possible orders

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am asked the find the possible orders of subgroups of a group of order $60$.

By Lagrange's theorem: $\left | H \right | | \left | G \right |$
Any positive integer $n$ that is a divisor of $\left | G \right |=60$ is a possible order of a subgroup of a group of order $60$.

The possible orders are $1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60$.

> Question: Find a group of order $60$ that has subgroup of all possible orders.

Is there a quick way to determine this?

Comment: How about the cyclic group of order 60?

Comment: @carmichael561 What is a quick way to determine that it has subgroup of all possible orders?

Comment: If $x$ is a generator of $C_{60}$, then $x^d$ has order $\frac{60}{d}$ for each divisor $d$ of 60, hence so does the subgroup it generates.

Comment: OP asks for a quicker method to determine the possible order for subgroups, which is equivalent to find the possible divisors of 60. If introduce the cyclic group of order 60, it is still to look for divisors of 60. I don't get what is the point of thinking of cyclic group? @carmichael561

Answer (score 1):

A finite supersolvable group has a subgroup for every possible order. $11$ of the $13$ groups of order $60$ are supersolvable, so you can use any of them.

The remaining groups, $A_5$ and $C_5\times A_4$, do not have the required property.

Note, that there are finite groups having a subgroup for every possible order which are not supersolvable, so the converse of the initial claim is false.

Comment: Now this is one as correct as uninstructive answer ...